# header("Content-Type: image/jpeg") not working

Tags: php

Having read through all the similar questions, no situation is like mine.
After cutting all the crap, my code is:

```
<?php
$file = 'Images\Bird1.jpg';
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($file);
?>
```

But it dispays a blank page. The path\file does exist, I checked it with code like:

```
if (file_exists($file))
```

The file type is indeed image/jpeg, this I also checked in the more extensive version of my code. Please help?

Answer (score 0):

```
imagejpeg($file);
```

This function requires a resource, not a filename. You are looking for

```
readfile($file);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php